# Class Attributes from configuration file

Tags: c#, .net

I want to initialize the class attributes from the configuration file such as:

```
    [LuisModel(modelID: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LUISAppId"], subscriptionKey: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LUISSubscription"], domain: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LUISDomain"])]
    [Serializable]
    public class NoteDialog : LuisDialog<object>
    {
    }
```

but I get the following error:

> An attribute argument must be a contant expression, typeof expression
>   or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Any idea if the class attributes can be read from a config file?

Comment: The settings within the file are a runtime-information. Attributes on the other hand are compile-time information. Thus what you want is not possible.

Comment: Technically you can change the values of the Instances of the attributes  at runtime for example by: using typeof(MyClass).GetCustomAttributes to get them and changing properties on them.